# UPDATE from SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

Sorry, I know nothing of SQL.

Please can somebody give me the SQL command to perform the following:

- UPDATE field "difficulty"
- of TABLE "data"
- with the value in field "rank" form the table "prime"
- WHERE the value of field "field2" of table "prime" = value of the field "english" of table "data"

I am using Sqlite.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is not a "we do the work for you" site. Show some effort.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ everything you need to know about sql, it isn't that hard to do this simple query.

Comment: Update with a subselect "too localized" ?  You gotta be kidding... I'll vote to reopen *sigh*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This untested (obviously, because I don't have your schema), but something like this:

```
UPDATE data SET difficulty = (SELECT rank FROM prime WHERE field2 = data.english);
```